# Delete command is deleting data rather than just the columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to reformat some sheets that receive their input from other macros. The input to the sheets is fine, but once I try to delete the columns that I need to get rid of (A:H) it only happens on one sheet and all of the data disappears on that sheet.

Here is my code:

```
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim current_flt_date, dept_time As Date
Dim dept_station, arrv_station, subfleet_type, route, red_eye As String
Dim current_flt_number As Integer

For Each wsSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Not wsSheet.Name = "Sheet3" Then
        wsSheet.Rows(1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(1).Value
        lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        wsSheet.Cells(1, lCol + 1) = "Qty Loaded"
        wsSheet.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        wsSheet.Rows(1).Font.Underline = True
        current_flt_date = wsSheet.Cells(2, 1)
        Debug.Print current_flt_date
        dept_station = wsSheet.Cells(2, 2)
        current_flt_number = wsSheet.Cells(2, 3)
        dept_time = wsSheet.Cells(2, 4)
        arrv_station = wsSheet.Cells(2, 5)
        subfleet_type = wsSheet.Cells(2, 6)
        Debug.Print subfleet_type
        route = wsSheet.Cells(2, 7)
        red_eye = wsSheet.Cells(2, 8)
        Range("A:H").Delete

    End If

Next wsSheet
```

I added some screens as well. The first one shows what happens without the delete and the second is with the delete.

[Without delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Lo2.jpg)

[image: With delete]

Comment: One more question: I added the following code to add 9 rows and am now getting a type mismatch: 'code' wsSheet.Rows("1, 10").Insert Shift:=xlDown , CopyOrgin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'code' Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the columns deleted on all the desired worksheets I think you should write:

```
wsSheet.Range("A:H").Delete
```

Also do you mean that columns that should not  have be deleted were deleted with your code?

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! So I was not being specific enough with my command? Fortunately, there is nothing that has been deleted that should not have been.